# how to load mysql data faster into jquery datatable

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, datatables

hi i am using jquery datatable plugin to load mysql data into it so far its goin good but when the records are more the data table gets relatively slow  to load so now i am stuck here and have no idea of what has to be done so can anyone help me in this 
here is my code

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mdb` ORDER BY grno");
?>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datatables').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
        "aaSorting":[[2, "desc"]],
        "bJQueryUI":true
    });
})

<table id="datatables" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Srno.</th>
           <th>Brno.</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Address</th>
           <th>City</th>
           <th>Pin</th>
           <th>Mobile</th>
           <th>Actions</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td align='center'>$row[grno]</td>";
               echo "<td align='center'>$row[brno]</td>";
               echo "<td align='center'>$row[name]</td>";
               echo "<td align='center'>$row[address]</td>";
               echo "<td align='center'>$row[city]</td>";
               echo "<td align='center'>$row[pin]</td>";
               echo "<td align='center'>$row[mobile]</td>";
               echo "<td><a href=\"entry.php?vouchno=$row[vouchno]\"><img src='images/edit.png'></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"delete.php?code=$row[vouchno]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Confrim Delete?');\"><img src='images/delete.png'></a></td>";
               echo "</tr>";
           }
           ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No more to say: http://www.datatables.net/development/pagination AND http://datatables.net/usage/server-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at [here](http://datatables.net/faqs#speed).

If you want to have server-side processing click [here](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html).